# Need practice with finding the derivative of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

I am really struggling with this concept of finding the derivative of an integral.$$f(x)=\int_x^{11}t^4\cos(t)dt$$ Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign this might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. We have
$$f(x)=\int_x^{11} t^4\cos(t)dt$$
Let $g(t)=t^4\cos(t)$ and let $G(x)$ be its antiderivative. Then
$$f(x)=G(11)-G(x)$$
Now, when we differentiate with respect to $x$, the $G(11)$ goes away because it is a constant, and when we differentiate $G(x)$ we end up with $g(x)$ since $G(x)$ is the antiderivative of $g(x)$, so
$$f'(x)=-g(x)$$
$$f'(x)=-x^4\cos(x)$$
If you have any questions, just ask!

Answer (score 1):

See Newton-Leibnitz theorem . If $f(x)=\int _{g (x)}^{m (x)} k (t) $ then $f'(x)=k (g (x))\cdot g'(x)-k (m (x))\cdot m'(x)$ so with this for your example $f'(x)=0-x^4\cos (x) $

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$\int_x^{11} t^4\cos(t)dt=-\int_{11}^xt^4\cos(t)$$
and fundamental theorem of calculus